# Mysql Connot add foreign key constraint. how can I resolve it?

Tags: mysql, database

I tried to excute the query. but a error was occurred. the error message is `'Cannot add foreign key constraint'`. 
I supposed to create this table. but it didn't work.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`member` (
      `idseq` INT(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      `pw` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `mobile0` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
      `mobile1` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
      `mobile2` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
      `mobile3` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
      `birth` DATE NOT NULL,
      `admin_YN` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
      `reg_date` DATE NOT NULL,
      `upd_date` DATE NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idseq`, `id`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 6
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`reservation` (
  `reservation_seq` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `playMv_seq` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `reservaion_seat_code` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `reservaion_seat_num` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `reservation_charge` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `reservation_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reservation_seq`, `user_id`, `playMv_seq`),

    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`member` (`id`)    
    )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 8
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

So I checked it detail from a query`'show engine innodb status`. the detail error message is

Error in foreign key constraint of table mydb/reservation:

```
 FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
     REFERENCES `mydb`.`member` (`id`)
```

Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
 referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
 in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
 Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
 tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
 cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.

how can I resolve the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to create a foreign key referencing the `id` column of the target table:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
REFERENCES `mydb`.`member` (`id`)
```

But what is the actual key on that target table?:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`idseq`, `id`)
```

It's not `id`, if the composite of `idseq` *and* `id`.  In order to reference that as a foreign key, you need local columns which match that:

```
`user_idseq` INT(1) NOT NULL,
`user_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
```

And use *both* of them for the foreign key:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`user_idseq`, `user_id`)
REFERENCES `mydb`.`member` (`idseq`, `id`)
```

(Side Note: That primary key in `member` looks pretty strange to me in the first place.  Why can't `idseq` by itself be the primary key?  What is the purpose of `id`?)

Comment: Thank you~! I work it from your comment. and Actually there is not a special reason about setting <code>idseq, id</code>  to the primary key. I thinked these are just set naturally. and these purpose is the same. I'm short of the database skills..